# .cartesian() in PySpark

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, pyspark

I created `rdd = sc.parallelize(range(200))`. Then I set `rdd2 = rdd.cartesian(rdd)`. I found that as expected `rdd2.count()` was 40,000. However, when I set `rdd3 = rdd2.cartesian(rdd)`, `rdd3.count()` was less than 20,000. Why is this the case?

Comment: This is quite strange indeed. I just tried the same sequence of operations in Scala and it resulted in an RDD with 8M items. In pyspark, for me, `rdd3.count()` resulted in 3200. Maybe it has something to do with the number of partitions?

Comment: More likely the way it is implemented. `cartesian` does some ugly serde tricks to reuse Java code. If am pretty sure you can open JIRA for that.

Comment: Even on Databricks cloud I see the same issue: https://databricks-prod-cloudfront.cloud.databricks.com/public/4027ec902e239c93eaaa8714f173bcfc/1698738444120167/2754566735493710/4750003467380621/latest.html

Did someone open a jira for that issue?


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vYoiH.png

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug tracked by [SPARK-16589](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-16589).